# Receiving error when adding more values to a list inside a for loop

Tags: java

I keep receiving the following error whenever i try running the below code with more than 5 values in hotelList. I think there is an error with the way im iterating over penalty and path, but im unsure as to how to fix it.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
    at First.main(First.java:81)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class First {


    public static void printPath(int path[], int i) {
        if (i == 0) return;
        printPath(path, path[i]);
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, java.io.IOException {

        Scanner dataFile = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\USER\\Documents\\Data.txt"));
        ArrayList<Integer> hotels = new ArrayList<>();
        hotels.add(0);
        while (dataFile.hasNextLine()) {
            hotels.add(dataFile.nextInt());
        }
        dataFile.close();
        //optimalStops(hotels);


        //int[] hotelList = new int[hotels.size()];

        /*for (int i = 0; i < hotels.size(); i++) {
            if (hotels.get(i) != null) {
                hotelList[i] = hotels.get(i);
            }*/

            int hotelList[] = {0, 66, 83, 130, 180, 1};
            int penalties[] = {0, (int) Math.pow(200 - hotelList[1], 2), -1, -1, -1};
            int path[] = {0, 0, -1, -1, -1};
            for (int i = 2; i <= hotelList.length - 1; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                    int tempPen = (int) (penalties[j] + Math.pow(200 - (hotelList[i] - hotelList[j]), 2));
                    if (penalties[i] == -1 || tempPen < penalties[i]) {
                        penalties[i] = tempPen;
                        path[i] = j;
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int i = 1; i < hotelList.length; i++) {
                System.out.print("Hotel: " + hotelList[i] + ", penalty: " + penalties[i] + ", path: ");
                printPath(path, i);
                System.out.println();
            }
```

Comment: When you say `penalties[j]`, and `j` is greater then the length of `penalties`, you get the error you describe. Note that you are checking `i` is less than `hotelList.length` (but you use it for indexing `penalties` and `path` as well).  And `hotelList` has `6` elements...

Answer (score 0):

Your penalties is only 5 items long. So when you call this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < hotelList.length; i++) {
    System.out.print("Hotel: " + hotelList[i] + ", penalty: " + penalties[i] + ", path: ");
```

You're trying to access penalties[5], which throws the out of bounds error.

You also have the same problem in this part of the code:

```
for (int i = 2; i <= hotelList.length - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    int tempPen = (int) (penalties[j] + Math.pow(200 - (hotelList[i] - hotelList[j]), 2));
    if (penalties[i] == -1 || tempPen < penalties[i]) {
        penalties[i] = tempPen;
        path[i] = j;
    } 
}
```

**I think your intent is to do something more like this:**

```
for (int i = 1; i < hotelList.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < penalties.length; j++){
        System.out.print("Hotel: " + hotelList[i] + ", penalty: " + penalties[j] + ", path: ");
```

I can't tell what your intent is in the other for loop. If you could explain what you're trying to accomplish, I might be able to help out.

Comment: I appreciate the help. Basically im trying to write a recursive method to solve the below problem for an arraylist of a 100 marker posts. Right now im just trying to solve the problem without the recursion, but am running into the loop errors. Am i going about solving this problem in the right way?

Comment: You are going on a long trip. You start on the road at mile post 0. Along the way there are n hotels, at mile posts a1 < a2 < ... < an, where each ai is measured from the starting point. The only places you are allowed to stop are at these hotels, but you can choose which of the hotels you stop at. You must stop at the final hotel (at distance an), which is your destination. You'd ideally like to travel 200 miles a day, but this may not be possible (depending on the spacing of the hotels).

Comment: If you travel x miles during a day, the penalty for that day is (200 - x)^2. You want to plan your trip so as to minimize the total penalty that is, the sum, over all travel days, of the daily penalties. Give an efficient algorithm that determines the optimal sequence of hotels at which to stop.